come out <as> successful

We often hear stories of people who jumped into the metaphorical ‘deep end’ in their line of work without any support, and came out on the other side as celebrated and successful.”

*source; ‘Louder than Words: Harness the Power of Your Authentic Voice’ by Todd Henry

Is the ‘as’ in the sentence above functioning grammatically the same way as the ‘as’ in ‘regard A as B’?
Is this ‘as’ in the sentence an essential component to construct the sentence?
What is the meaning difference between 'come out  successful' and 'come out successful' without as?

Would much appreciate your responses.

Normally you'd use as with a noun or noun phrase:

He started the families warring and emerged from the melee as head of the syndicate.

and omit as with adjectives and adjectival phrases:

He started the street war and emerged more powerful than before.

I find the example you cited not quite grammatical.

Business was bad for a while but things came out as okay. ungrammatical


Things came out okay.
Things came out better than expected.
The woolen sweater came out of the clothes dryer quite shrunken.


I add to what TimR said.
The version with as is normally for cases with nouns or noun phrases after as; and that without as, for adjectives or adjective phrases.
We look at a similar pair:
emerged as successful and emerged successful.
Among the positive hits, we can find also cases with as used with adjectives or adjective phrases like this one:

... it would appear from the teachers who emerged as successful in the tasks ...

and this:

... that would not have emerged as “successful” if they ...

Hence both versions are valid, and they mean the same:

... came out on the other side as celebrated and successful.


... came out on the other side celebrated and successful.

The above is for cases without another success story to be compared against,  like the OP’s example.
However, if another story and an intention to compare are added before this, I'll use as even if what follows is an adjective or adjective phrase:
... came out on the other side as celebrated and successful (as the other one).
The bracketed prepositional phrase is optional.

Thanks for your response but I think 'came out on the other side as celebrated and successful (as the other one)' would be possible because there's a comparison: as celebrated and successful as.
